# How to read the label(annotation) file from Synthia Dataset?

Tags: python, deep-learning, dataset, semantic-segmentation

I am new to Synthia dataset. I would like to read the label file from this datset. I expect to have one channel matrix with size of my RGB image, but when I load the data I got 3x760x1280 and it is full of zeros.

I tried to read as belows:

label = np.asarray(imread(label_path))

Can anyone help to read these labels file correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the right way to read it as below:

label = np.asarray(imageio.imread(label_path, format='PNG-FI'))[:,:,0]